# Sound is not working in Ubuntu Linux 22.04.3 LTS system

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, multimedia

Suddenly my sound system has stopped working since this morning. I tried all the available options available in the Internet from checking the sound option in the settings section followed by adjusting the "alsamixer" in the terminal. I even checked my MSI laptop whether I accidentally muted the sound. Also, I uninstalled the pulse-audio and reinstalled it, yet the sound is not back. I have no idea why this happened. I don't think I have changed anything in the settings option yesterday. I was listening to some YouTube videos and some songs and everything worked fine until yesterday night. Let me know how to get back the sounds in my system. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check your Sound over an ubuntu live session like your install media?